# Hadoop: Set slave as explicit reducer?

Tags: dictionary, hadoop, mapreduce, reduce, slave

we use a hadoop multi-node setup on debian + ubuntu with the latest stable hadoop release. is it possible to set a specific slave to be the reducer? i just use one reducer task and i want to assign it to the most performant slave. atm we have 1 master, who just assignes the tasks to the slaves and 5 slaves, one is more powerful than the others.

thanks in advance

Comment: If you already know which the high performing node is and you are running a single reducer, couldn't you just remove the names of the other nodes from the slaves file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable reducer slots on all other nodes by setting `mapred.tasktracker.reduce.tasks.maximum` to 0 in all `conf/mapred-site.xml` files (except the one node that you want to reduce).

Or, you could write a custom LoadManager class for the Fair Scheduler (see [this](http://hadoop.apache.org/mapreduce/docs/r0.21.0/fair_scheduler.html)), but it's a lot more work.